# Tomcat 8 slow applications initialization

Tags: windows, tomcat

I found quite a few threads on "slow start" of Tomcat, but none related to slow web applications initialization.

I am using a Tomcat 8 with Java 8.  Most of the time it uses only a fraction of the memory and CPU capacity.  The server starts quickly but the web applications themselves initialize very slowly (10-15 minutes for a dozen simple apps).

Some details that might be relevant:

- The servers are Tomcat 8 running on Java 8.
- The applications are all built with Spring MVC.
- All applications rely on the exact same stack of open source libraries, with their classpaths specified in catalina.properties common.loader. (cas, commons-beanutils, commons-dbcp2, cxf, itext, jackson, jt400, mssql jdbc driver, poi, sitemesh and spring, plus the libraries they depend on)
- We have a similar servers also running Tomcat 8 on Java 8, but using Java 6 emulation to run older applications.  Those applications rely on older versions of the same open source libraries.  These old-app servers do start in a reasonable time.  The only obvious difference is the open source packing model (the older approach of collecting them into a few dozen jars compared to the modern hundreds of smaller jars).
- A native Java 8 application that uses the same newer version of the library stack starts up even faster, in seconds.

A 10-15 minute wait before the web applications are initialized and available is too long.  I assume that we are doing something wrong to cause such slow initialization.

Can I ask for some hints on how to troubleshoot and solve this problem?

Thanks.

---

In case it is relevant, this is the start of the catalina.log, including the first couple apps that come with Tomcat:

```
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.952 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Oct 7 2015 18:25:21 UTC
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.28.0
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows Server 2012 R2
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.3
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             D:\java\jdk8.144\jre
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.28
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.28
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.28
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.28
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\endorsed
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\temp
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\conf\logging.properties
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xdebug
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: exit
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms3000m
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx4000m
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.33 using APR version 1.5.1.
26-Jun-2019 05:59:02.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
26-Jun-2019 05:59:04.030 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1m 19 Mar 2015)
26-Jun-2019 05:59:04.561 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-80"]
26-Jun-2019 05:59:04.623 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-443"]
26-Jun-2019 05:59:05.108 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
26-Jun-2019 05:59:05.108 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
26-Jun-2019 05:59:05.123 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 3442 ms
26-Jun-2019 05:59:05.170 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
26-Jun-2019 05:59:05.170 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
26-Jun-2019 05:59:05.202 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\webapps\docs
26-Jun-2019 05:59:40.780 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
26-Jun-2019 05:59:40.936 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\webapps\docs has finished in 35,750 ms
26-Jun-2019 05:59:40.936 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\webapps\examples
26-Jun-2019 06:00:11.998 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
26-Jun-2019 06:00:12.467 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\webapps\examples has finished in 31,531 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting a high value for Xms seems excessive. Try leaving this at default, a minimum of 3g rising to max of 4g is quite narrow. You apps may need this RAM but they should grow to fill space on their own